# Shell sort by month

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, unix

This is text.txt

```
APR
AUG
DEC
FEB
JAN
JUL
JUN
MAR
MAY
NOV
OCT
SEP
```

I had try

```
sort -k1M text.txt
sort -M test.txt
```

It also can't sort by the month like

```
Jan
Feb
Mar
bla bla bla...
```

Any mistake at my command?
thank you

Comment: Which platform are you working on?  Does your `sort` support `-M`?  It worked OK on Mac OS X 10.9.3 with `/usr/bin/sort`, which is GNU `sort` (version 5.93; hardly the most recent version).  It'll probably work OK with other more recent versions of GNU `sort`.  Do you have LANG or LC_ALL or similar environment variables set?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. What version of `sort` are you using?

Comment: Linux redhat 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64, sort (GNU coreutils) 8.4

Comment: When I sort --help, it had : -M, --month-sort            compare (unknown) < `JAN' < ... < `DEC'

Comment: should work. If you created the file on Windows, then do `dos2unix fileWithDates` and try again. Good luck.

Comment: Can I define a sort rule for my scripts / files ? Let say sort by "Dec, Jan, Mar, Jul, Nov"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can reproduce this issue with GNU sort 8.21 and a default time locale different than english, which may be your case.

First, check the current setting for date/time values:

```
grille@ced10:~$ locale | grep -i time

LC_TIME="it_IT.UTF-8"
```

In fact mine is not english, so `sort -m` won't work as expected with english month names:

```
grille@ced10:~$ cat /tmp/mesi

AUG
JAN
JUL
FEB


grille@ced10:~$ sort -M /tmp/mesi

AUG
JAN
JUL
FEB
```

The solution is to temporarily alter the LC_TIME value to an english one:

```
grille@ced10:~$ LC_TIME="en_EN.UTF-8" sort -M /tmp/mesi

JAN
FEB
JUL
AUG
```

Don't worry about messing up things, because after the execution of the command in which locale variable was altered, its original value is automatically restored:

```
grille@ced10:~$ locale | grep -i time

LC_TIME="it_IT.UTF-8"
```

have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

1.Please check invisible (nonprinting) symbols in your text file using e.g.

```
cat -v your_text_file
```

or

```
od -xc your_text_file|head
```

2.Exclude possible ambiguity by starting "sort --version"  and  sort of your text file specifying absolute path of sort.